# load page from controller in electron js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I'm new in electron and trying to load new page from `controller` on `button click` but it does not load page neither gives any error.

this is my controller code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('appCtrl', [
            '$scope',
            '$location',
            '$window',
            '$http',
            '$rootScope',
            function ($scope, $location, $window, $http, $rootScope) {
                $scope.fun = function () {
                    $location.url('./admin/Logout.html');
                };
            }
        ])
    }
)();
```

I don't what I'm doing wrong but I'm totally stuck over here. So any kind of help will be appreciated.